# Qttelegrambot not receiving message from php

Tags: php, qt, telegram

I´m using this library [QtTelegramBot](https://github.com/moritzsternemann/QtTelegramBot) and my Qt app can send/receive messages to/from Official Telegram app and my cel phone bot.

When I sent a message from php using a code like this:

```
<?php

$bottoken='here is my telegram token';

$request_params=[
            "chat_id"           =>  "my id telegram",
            "text"              =>  "my message",
        ];

$request_url="https://api.telegram.org/bot". $bottoken . '/sendMessage?' .http_build_query($request_params);
file_get_contents($request_url);

echo "sent";

?>
```

This code sent message correctly to Official Desktop Telegram client and my cell phone. But my Qt app using QtTelegrambot library not receive anything.

Comment: this library is pretty good and easy to use!

Answer (score 0):

I understand better this problem....using php to send messages, bot is the sender and the user is the receiver....my Qt app cannot receive message from himself.